# Prove that there exists $\xi \in (a,b)$, such that $f(\xi)+f'(\xi)=\xi + 1$

Tags: calculus

$f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f(a)=a$, and $$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\frac{b^2-a^2}{2}.$$

Prove that there exists $\xi \in (a,b)$, such that $f(\xi)+f'(\xi)=\xi + 1$

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do we know that $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$?

Comment: If you also had $f(b)=b$, then you could apply MVT to
$$\int_a^b f(x) \, dx - \int_a^b x \, dx + f(b)-f(a) - (b-a)$$
and this would give you the result you want.

Comment: you might want to add some condition for the derivative... Say that it is continuous. As to the problem, if such point \ksi does not exist then we have strict inequality between two sides. You can then deduce the inequality for $f...$

Comment: @process91: If $f(b)=b$, then the conclusion is very easy.

Comment: @JimmyK4542: I don't know whether $f$ is differentiable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x)=g(x)+x.$ Then, $g(a)=0$ and
$$\int_{a}^bg(x)dx=0.$$

What you want to prove is that there exists a point $x_0$ such that $g(x_0)+g'(x_0)=0.$ If $g(x)=0$ everywhere on $[a,b]$ then you are done. Otherwise, from the integral condition, it follows that at some points of the interval, the function is positive and at others it is negative. Therefore, if we consider $h(x)=e^xg(x),$ we have that $\max h>0$ and $\min h<0.$ Since $h(a)=0,$ either maximum or minimum occurs at the point $x_0$ inside the interval $(a,b).$
At this point, $h'(x_0)=0=e^{x_0}(g(x_0)+g'(x_0))=0$ and the result follows.

Comment: You are talent！